# Pyramid and Beaker: ValueError: insecure string pickle

Tags: python, pickle, pyramid, beaker

I'm having some trouble with Pyramid and Beaker (using pyramid_beaker and a memcached backend). This error started happening seemingly at random (I wasn't making any changes in the code) and it persists on requests that don't even use `request.session`.

I'm really not sure where to start with this, but have tried restarting memcached and using a different instance of memcached and secret. Caching was working correctly earlier. If anyone has suggestions to check I can provide more information.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.7.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 154, in __call__
    result = template.render_unicode(**system)
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/mako/template.py", line 311, in render_unicode
    as_unicode=True)
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/templates/toolbar.mako", line 61, in render_body
    ${panel.content()|n}
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/request_vars.py", line 44, in content
    'session': dictrepr(self.request.session),
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/utils.py", line 145, in dictrepr
    for val in d:
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/beaker/session.py", line 672, in __iter__
    return iter(self._session().keys())
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/beaker/session.py", line 646, in _session
    **params)
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/beaker/session.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/beaker/session.py", line 324, in load
    self.namespace.acquire_read_lock()
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/beaker/container.py", line 211, in acquire_read_lock
    self.open('r', checkcount = True)
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/beaker/container.py", line 243, in open
    self.do_open(flags, replace)
  File "/var/www/web/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Beaker-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/beaker/container.py", line 659, in do_open
    self.hash = cPickle.load(fh)
ValueError: insecure string pickle
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a root cause, but after two hours it appears to be working again - as far as I can guess a cache invalidated or something timed out.